# is it possible to create this dashboard in power BI?

Tags: powerbi, reporting

I am just starting out with Power BI. So far it has been easy to learn. My goal is to create a dashboard like this:

https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/

I am just wondering if someone knows an interactive power bi sample like this. Is it even possible to create such reports in power BI?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes. It is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to create dashboards like this. See for example [Power BI Embedded Playground](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/demo/v2-demo/index.html) or Microsoft Sales & Returns report ([download](https://github.com/MikeCarlo/Msft-Skateboard-Report) or [view in browser](https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiMTFmNThlYzUtYTZhOS00MWE0LWE2ZDQtMjhlNmNmYWMwOGVjIiwidCI6IjcyNDQ1YmFhLTMxNGYtNGM5Mi05MzY0LTFjYjJjNDkyNGJmNiIsImMiOjN9)):

[image]